# Knowing the event stack size

Tags: c#, events, count, stack, size

I'm facing a tricky problem and I hope you guys will be able to help!

An application I'm working on is getting slow at some point of its lifetime and I suspect it's related to incoming events.

In order to clarify this behavior and know if it's the actual source of my nightmares, I would like to trace the event stack size.

So do you guys know a way to know how many events are queued, waiting to be processed by the event handler of my application?

Is it possible to change this value ? Does my question make any sense?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's the core of an application that is designed to be launched from as console app, winforms app or simple a service. In my case, it's started from as a console app.

Comment: What is the source of your events? Do they come from the same thread? from another thread? from another process? from the hardware? from user interaction? from the web? I think that this is a very important factor in your case.

Comment: I receive lots of event from an external application (on the same computer). To treat this event, we start a chain of 7 events travelling through our application that finally starts a thread. I suspect that all those events, after being thrown, stack up and fill completely the events stack, causing the whole application to slow up badly ! In worst case, it's totally possible to receive many hundreds of even from the external application each seconds !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is not a direct answer to your question but i usually do my performance tuning with the help of profiling software. For .NET i can recommend jetbrains dotTrace but i'm sure you'll find one in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers).

Comment: I'll try some of those tools, it will certainly help me ! Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 1):

This might depend on what kind of event you're handling. I guess that events in winform enviroments have a good part of overhead but that might not be the problem.

Another setup is to simply let all events 'post' a workitem into a list and let the 'worker' threads empty the work list. This lets you see the workitem list and gives you some control/directions to optimize the code.